# Expected value and variance of $X$

Tags: probability

If I know that $N \sim {\rm Ge}(p)$ and I set $X = (-1)^N$

How do I find $E[X]$ and ${\rm Var}[X]$?

Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: Ge(p) means geometric distribution? What are your thougths?

Comment: Yeah, Ge(p) means geometric. Honestly, I don't know where to begin. I know that EX = SUM(xp(x)) and VarX = SUM((x-EX)^2) but how do I find p(x)? Would I be summing over the k of the geometric prob func?

Comment: You want to use the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either compute the probability distribution of $X$ (you see it can take only two values, $-1$ or $1$) ,  or you can compute the expectations directly.

For the later, recall that the formula $E[Z] = \sum_z z \, p_Z(z)$ also applies to any function of the random variable: $E[g(Z)] = \sum_z g(z) \, p_Z(z)$. In our case:

$$E[X] = E[(-1)^N] = \sum_n (-1)^n p_N(n) $$

where $p_N(n)$ is the geometric distribution. In the same wayu we can compute $E[X^2]$

Comment: I think you should say $E[(-1)^N]=\sum_n (-1)^n p_N(n)$, with a capital $N$ in the two places where you see it here, and a lower-case $n$ in the three places where you see it here.  Capital $N$ is a random variable; lower-case $n$ is the index of summation.  They're not the same thing.  And what is $p_N(3)$, for example?  The "$N$" is not the same thing as the "$3$".

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yes, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, and you too @MichaelHardy! This helped tremendously. EX = p/(2-p) and VarX = 4(1-p)/(2-p)^2.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Pr(X=1) = \sum_{n\text{ even}} \Pr(N=n)$$
and $\Pr(X=-1)=1-\Pr(X=1)$.  It's really easy to find this sum because it's a geometric series.  The common ratio is $(1-p)^2$ (or $p^2$, depending on which you call $p$ and which you call $1-p$).

But it is not clear whether you mean the geometric distribution supported on the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ or the one supported on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.  If the former, then $0$ is one of the even numbers in the sum.

$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 = 1 - (E(X))^2.
$$

Comment: So, for 0 <= p <= 1; P(X=1) = 1/(2-p) and P(X=-1) = (1-p)/(2-p)